# Как исправить ошибку "Unknown column 'param_id' in 'field list'"?

Tags: mysql

При конвертации в JBZoo каталога продуктов, через стандартный инструмент миграция, получаю ошибку:

```
Unknown column 'param_id' in 'field list' SQL=INSERT INTO fcjf2_zoo_jbzoo_sku 
    (`item_id`, `element_id`, `param_id`, `value_s`, `value_n`, `value_d`, `variant`)
     VALUES 
     ('9', '8390ceb6-3e83-4904-80f8-09e7bbc4d987', '_sku', '1', '1', NULL, '0'),
     ('9', '8390ceb6-3e83-4904-80f8-09e7bbc4d987', '_value', '2890', '2890', '2890-02-23 22:21:56', '0'),
     ('9', '8390ceb6-3e83-4904-80f8-09e7bbc4d987', '_discount', '1', '1', NULL, '0'), 
     ('9', '8390ceb6-3e83-4904-80f8-09e7bbc4d987', '_balance', '1', '1', NULL, '0'), 
     ('9', '8390ceb6-3e83-4904-80f8-09e7bbc4d987', '_sku', '1', '1', NULL, '-1'), 
     ('9', '8390ceb6-3e83-4904-80f8-09e7bbc4d987', '_value', '2890', '2890', '2890-02-23 22:21:56', '-1'),
     ('9', '8390ceb6-3e83-4904-80f8-09e7bbc4d987', '_discount', '1', '1', NULL, '-1'),
     ('9', '8390ceb6-3e83-4904-80f8-09e7bbc4d987', '_balance', '1', '1', NULL, '-1')
```

Почему возникает ошибка и как ее устранить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка означает, что в таблице `fcjf2_zoo_jbzoo_sku` отсутствует поле `param_id`